# Need an explanation for this snippet of javascript code for capturing links

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, while-loop, tagging

The following code snippet is needed to capture html links for my site. Although, it seems to work, I wish to have an explanation so that I may improve upon it. Can someone give me a quick summary of what's happening in this code? I don't especially understand the while statement that uses this variable 'link'. What is 'link'? A dummy variable of some sort like you would use in a dictionary or map iteration? Also, why use document.links[0]?

```
 if (document.links){
  if (document.links[0]){
   var links = document.links, link, k=0;
   while(link=links[k++]) {
    link.onclick = linkCapture;
   }
  }
 }

function linkCapture() {
  this.parent = this.parentNode;
  eventCapture('Link Click','Page Tag',this.name,this.href);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if (document.links){
```

The browser supports the property:

```
  if (document.links[0]){
```

There is at least one link:

```
   var links = document.links, link, k=0;
```

Standard initialization

```
   while(link=links[k++]) {
```

For every run through the loop, set link to the next element, then increment k.  Exit the loop when the current `links[k]` is falsy (probably because we've passed the last element).

```
    link.onclick = linkCapture;
```

Set the onclick property to linkCapture.

This really isn't great code to begin with.  You could write the whole thing using jQuery like:

```
$(document.links).click(linkCapture);
```

As a bonus, you wouldn't risk overwriting an existing `onclick` property.

Comment: _"You could write the whole thing like..."_ - if you use jQuery. (Which I do recommend, but which you didn't actually name.)

Comment: @nnnnnn, yeah, I meant to add that, but then I forgot why I had an edit window open. :)

Comment: Thank you so very much. You're awesome. I would very much like to use jQuery in a future implementation rather than this and similar code. Any suggestions on what I should focus on to capture not only links, but button clicks, anonymous form submits,and other user interaction on a web page that I could capture? Again, thank you.

Comment: @Brian, jQuery provides [:button](http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/) and [submit](http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/), which should be helpful.  If this answers your question, please click the checkmark.